# How to replace node-sass with sass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

I was trying to replace `node-sass` with `sass` in `react`, so I have updated the `package.json` file and removed `node-sass`, and added `sass`. Since the updated version of `sass-loader` works with `Dart sass` it should have worked fine.

`package.json` -- old

```
"node-sass" : "^7.0.0",
"sass-loader": "10.1.0",
"webpack": "5.10.1"
```

`package.json` -- updated

```
"sass" : "^1.29.0",
"sass-loader": "10.1.0",
"webpack": "5.10.1"
```

But in the `package-lock.json` I could node-sass is still present.

```
"peerDependencies": {
   "fibers": ">= 3.1.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0",
   "sass": "^1.3.0",
   "webpack": "^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0"
 },
 "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "fibers": {
    "optional": true
   },
    "node-sass": {
     "optional": true
    },
    "sass": {
     "optional": true
    }
  }
```

I tried updating `sass` and `sass-loader` to the updated version it's still not working, also while compiling in `webpack` I get this error

```
node_modules\async-helpers\index.js:162
[ERROR]     throw new TypeError('expected helpers to be an object');
```